# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Data.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I know this question has been asked numerous times in the past but for me nothing doing.Here is my controller method due to which i am getting the error.

```
public PartialViewResult _CalendarDisplaySystem(AppointmentsViewModel appointmentsViewModel, Int32 pgNm, Int32 pgSz, Int32 sortCondition, string sortDirection, string GlobalSubmitVar, bool? chkIsCompleted,bool? chkIsBillPaid, string selectedVisitDate, string searchByVisitType, string searchByLocation, string searchByProvider)
        {
            IList<Appointments> obj = null;
            if (appointmentsViewModel == null)
            {
                appointmentsViewModel = new AppointmentsViewModel();
            }
            try
            {
                bool bIsCompleted = chkIsCompleted.HasValue ? chkIsCompleted.Value : false;
                bool bIsBillPaid = chkIsBillPaid.HasValue ? chkIsBillPaid.Value : false;
                if (searchByVisitType == "" && searchByLocation == "" && searchByProvider == "")
                {
                    return PartialView(appointmentsViewModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (GlobalSubmitVar == "1")
                    {
                        IList<Locations> locations = null;
                        locations = LocationsBo.LoadAll().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
                        string locationsText = string.Empty;
                        if (locations.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            for (int icount = 0; icount < locations.Count(); icount++)
                            {
                                locationsText += locations[icount].Name + ";";
                            }
                        }
                        searchByLocation = locationsText.ToString();

                        IList<VisitType> visitType = null;
                        visitType = VisitTypeBo.LoadAll().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.VisitTypeName).ToList();
                        string visitTypeText = string.Empty;
                        if (visitType.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            for (int icount = 0; icount < visitType.Count(); icount++)
                            {
                                visitTypeText += visitType[icount].VisitTypeName + ";";

                            }
                        }
                        searchByVisitType = visitTypeText.ToString();

                        IList<Provider> Provider = null;
                        Provider = ProviderBo.LoadAll().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.ProvName).ToList();
                        string ProviderText = string.Empty;
                        if (Provider.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            for (int icount = 0; icount < Provider.Count(); icount++)
                            {
                                ProviderText += Provider[icount].ProvName + ";";

                            }
                        }
                        searchByProvider = ProviderText.ToString();

                    }
                    obj = AppointmentsBo.LoadAllAppointments(pgNm, pgSz, sortCondition, sortDirection, bIsCompleted,bIsBillPaid, Convert.ToDateTime(selectedVisitDate), Convert.ToInt32(Enums.AppointmentCalendarStatus.Seen), searchByVisitType, searchByLocation, searchByProvider).ToList();
                    // Convert the 24 hours time to 12 hours time with AM/PM
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int hour = Convert.ToInt16(obj[i].StartTime.Split(':')[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt16(obj[i].StartTime.Split(':')[1]);
                        obj[i].StartTime = (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + hour + ":" + min)).ToString("hh:mm tt").ToUpper().Trim();

                        hour = Convert.ToInt16(obj[i].EndTime.Split(':')[0]);
                        min = Convert.ToInt16(obj[i].EndTime.Split(':')[1]);
                        obj[i].EndTime = (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + hour + ":" + min)).ToString("hh:mm tt").ToUpper().Trim();
                    }
                    appointmentsViewModel.AppointmentModel = obj.ToList();

                    //return PartialView(appointmentsViewModel);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Content(e.Message.ToString());
            }
            return PartialView(appointmentsViewModel);
        }
```

The problem here is when I am running the application locally it doesn't throw any exception but the same page when I want to open via IIS i get exception,Can somebody tell me what may be the issue.

**Here's the Stack-Trace**

Exception:An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Data.dll

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: The partial view '_CalendarDisplaySystem' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/CalendarDisplaySystem/_CalendarDisplaySystem.aspx
~/Views/CalendarDisplaySystem/_CalendarDisplaySystem.ascx
~/Views/Shared/_CalendarDisplaySystem.aspx
~/Views/Shared/_CalendarDisplaySystem.ascx
~/Views/CalendarDisplaySystem/_CalendarDisplaySystem.cshtml
~/Views/CalendarDisplaySystem/_CalendarDisplaySystem.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/_CalendarDisplaySystem.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_CalendarDisplaySystem.vbhtml
   at System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Please post the stack-trace.

Comment: And which `Data.dll`? Your own or the ADO.NET one?

Comment: A stackoverflow exception usually means a stack-dive caused by infinite recursion. Since `_CalendarDisplaySystem` doesn't call itself, this most-likely means one of the properties or methods on your objects (like `Locations`, etc) is broken. We can't tell which without the code. If you step through the code, how far do you get before it explodes. Find when it breaks, then run it again and stop the line before. Now step *into*, etc. The debugger is powerful: use it.

Comment: but the problem arises only when I run the hosted application not the local one,how to debug a hosted application

Comment: you do it the old school way, write a logging.